# Allocating multidimensional char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read lines from a file and store them in a multidimensional char pointer. When I run my code, it runs without errors, however, the lines will not be printed correctly in my main() function, but prints correctly in the getline() function. Can anybody explain what is happening and how I correctly store them in my multidimensional pointer?

My code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char **s = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1000);
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(s[i]) != -1){
        printf("In array: %s \n", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getline(char *s){
    s = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1000);
    int c, i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        s[i++] = c;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("String: %s \n", s);
    if (c == EOF) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**and my output:**

```
String: First line
<br>In array: (null) 
<br>String: Second line 
<br>In array: (null) 
<br>String: Third line 
<br>In array: (null)
```

Comment: Why do you handle the cast of the result of `malloc` differently in your code? However: [do not cast its result.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing by value.  Even though you change the value of `*s` in `getline()`, main does not see it.  You have to pass the address of `s[i]` so that `getline()` can change it:

```
int getline(char **s) {
  * s= malloc( sizeof(char) * 1000) ;
  ...
}
```

Also, if you want to be a bit more efficient with memory, read the line into a local buffer (of size 1000) if you want.  Then when you are done reading the line, allocate only the memory you need to store the actual string.

```
int getline( char ** s )
{
  char tmpstr[1000] ;
  ...
    tmpstr[i++]= c ;
  }
  tmpstr[i]= '\0' ;

  * s= strdup( tmpstr) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

If you want to improve things even further, take a step back and thing about a few things.  1) allocating the two parts of the multi-dimensional array in two different functions is going to make it harder for others to understand.  2) passing in a temporary string from outside to `getline()` would allow it to be significantly simpler:

```
int main()
{
  char ** s= (char **) malloc( 1000 * sizeof(char *)) ;
  char tmpstr[1000] ;
  int i ;

  while ( -1 != getline( tmpstr))
  {
    s[i ++]= strdup( tmpstr) ;
  }

  return 0 ;
}

int getline( char * s)
{
  int c, i = 0 ;
  while (( '\n' != ( c= getchar())) && ( EOF != c )) { s[i ++]= c ; }
  s[i]= '\0' ;

  return ( EOF == c ) ? -1 : 0 ;
}
```

Now, `getline` is just about IO, and all the allocation of `s` is handled in one place, and thus easier to reason about.

Comment: And how would the main() function look like?

Comment: In case 2, main would call `getline()` with `&(s[i])` instead of `s[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line inside `getline` function

```
s = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000); // Should be sizeof(char), not sizeof(char*)
```

has no effect on the `s[i]` pointer passed in. This is because pointers are passed by value.

You have two choices here:

- Move your memory allocation into `main`, and keep passing the pointer, or
- Keep your allocation in `getline`, but pass it a pointer to pointer from `main`.

Here is how you change `main` for the first option:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char **s = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1000);
    int i = 0;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        s[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
        if (getline(s[i]) == -1) break;
        printf("In array: %s \n", s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use malloc in the first place. malloc is very very dangerous!!
Just use `s[1000][1000]` and pass `&s[0][0]` for the first line, `&s[1][0]` for the second line etc.

For printing `printf("%s \n", s[i]);` where i is the line you want.

Comment: And using fixed size buffers on the stack is not dangerous?!? Are you an NSA-employee trying to coax people into writing insecure code?

Comment: it will be outside of the main function obviously!

Comment: That does not make fixed size buffer on the stack any better. Whatever size you choose for your buffer, you *will* at some point exceed it, and then you *will* have trouble finding out why your program is crashing. And you *will* limit your users to not supplying longer lines. Really, 99% of all fixed buffer sizes I have seen are bugs in disguise.

Comment: And using realloc in a loop is a great thing obviously!

Comment: You dont get it do you? He used malloc with a fixed size 1000. So I answered dont use malloc but use s[1000][1000] instead. What is the problem?

Comment: The one is as bad as the other. Both are bugs. The only difference is, that the buffer on the stack is much more easily exploited.

Comment: _Why do you use malloc in the first place.. malloc is very very dangerous!!_  I could not make up my mind whether to down vote you, or up vote you.  The down vote for the silliness of your statement.  The upvote for the entertainment value of it.  So, +1 (and -1).

Comment: Just use malloc in a threaded application and see who is going to laugh. And secondly why every large application does manualy memory managment without using malloc. I dont remember making fun of anybody. Maybe you are a smartass after all!

Answer (score 0):

My advise: completely avoid writing your own `getline()` function, and avoid all fixed size buffers. In the POSIX.1-2008 standart, there is already a `getline()` function. So you can do this:

```
//Tell stdio.h that we want POSIX.1-2008 functions
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char** s = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        count++;
        s = realloc(s, count*sizeof(char*));
        s[count-1] = NULL;    //so that getline() will allocate the memory itself
    } while(getline(&s[count-1], NULL, stdin));

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) printf(s[i]);
}
```